# Extract numbers from filenames disregarding extensions

Tags: bash, sed, grep, file-rename

I'm making a script to rename some video files. Some are named `XXX blah blah.ext` and some are `XXX - XXX blah blah.ext` where "X" are digits. Furthermore, some files are .avi and some are mp4. What I'd like is to extract the numbers from these files, separated by a space if there is more than one, and to disregard the "4" in ".mp4" files.

My current implementation is `egrep -o "[[:digit:]]*"`, and while this does separate numbers into different outputs, it also considers ".mp4".

Using sed I've not only not been able to produce different outputs for every number, but it also includes the "4". Note: I'm very new to sed i.e. I began learning it for the purpose of writing this script.

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't +1 because I don't have enough reputation, but thanks to all of you. You were really helpful and I learnt a few things about sed looking at your commands. I'll stick to "potong's", though, as it is the most "streamlined" and expandable to any number of digits (I do realize I could alter the other two for this). Thank again!

Comment: Don't forget to mark his as accepted then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in *
do
    echo $file | sed 's/\..*$//' | egrep -o "[[:digit:]]*"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You should find this to be pretty robust:

```
sed 's/^[^[:digit:]]*\([[:digit:]]\+\)[^[:digit:]]\+\( [[:digit:]]\+\)\?[^[:digit:]]\+[[:digit:]]\?$/\1\2/'
```

If your `sed` supports `-r`, you can eliminate the backslashes which are used for escaping:

```
sed -r 's/^[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]+( [[:digit:]]+)?[^[:digit:]]+[[:digit:]]?$/\1\2/'
```

Demo:

```
$ echo '123 blah blah.avi
234 blah blah.mp4
345 - 678 blah blah.avi
901 - 234 blah blah.mp4' | 
sed -r 's/^[^[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]+( [[:digit:]]+)?[^[:digit:]]+[[:digit:]]?$/\1\2/'
123
234
345 678
901 234
```

This depends on there being a space in the filename before the second number (when there is one). If there are files that don't have that, then a simple modification can make it work.

Comment: Full marks for the regex however isn't `[:digit:]` a bit OTT when `[0-9]` is suffice?

Comment: @potong: The OP used it and it will work in locales that use characters other than `[0-9]` for digits.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
# echo '123 bla bla.avi
456 - 789 bla bla.avi
012bla bla.avi
345-678blabla.avi
901 bla bla.mp4
234 - 567 bla bla.mp4
890bla bla.mp4
123 - 456 - 789 bla bla.mp4' |
sed 's/[^0-9]*[0-9]$//;s/[^0-9]\+/ /g'
123 
456 789 
012 
345 678 
901
234 567
890
123 456 789
```